# How to parse JSON response from DuckDuckGo Answers API using Retrofit2?

Tags: json, gson, retrofit2, duckduckgo-api

I'm trying to obtain POJO instances using Gson and Retrofit2.

A typical JSON response looks like [this](https://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=stack+overflow&format=json&pretty=1).

My issue is with the `Infobox` field. In some cases, (like [this](https://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=joey+tribbiani&format=json&pretty=1)) the field would be an object of the following type and an empty string otherwise.

```
class Infobox {
    public List<Content> content = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<Metum> meta;
}

class Content {
    public String dataType;
    public String value;
    public String label;
    public Integer wikiOrder;
}

class Metum {
    public String dataType;
    public String value;
    public String label;
}
```

I tried writing a TypeAdapter as below

```
class InfoboxAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Infobox> {
    final Gson embedded = new Gson();

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Infobox infobox) throws IOException {
        if (infobox == null) {
            out.nullValue();
            return;
        }
        out.beginObject();
        out.name("content");
        embedded.toJson(embedded.toJsonTree(infobox.content), out);

        out.name("meta");
        embedded.toJson(embedded.toJsonTree(infobox.meta), out);
        out.endObject();
    }

    @Override
    public Infobox read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        if ("".equals(in.peek())) {
            return null;
        }

        return embedded.fromJson(in, Infobox.class);
    }
```

But it fails with `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING`

The more confusing fact is that the field `meta` in the response, which is also an object, will in some cases have the value as null (and not an empty string like `infobox`)

I'd prefer to be able to do it using Gson as I've used it for everything else and I don't want to add another dependency

Comment: Hi please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please go to :http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
paste your code. this sites automatically create your all related classes.

if issue please have a look at this link.

[my drive link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6S5Da-5m4x-VklyZU9xX09XOUE)

Comment: I know about this site. As you can see in the question, I already have the POJO to represent Infobox. The issue is that when infobox does not have data, it returns `""` instead of `null`. These are two different datatypes and that trips Gson into throwing exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a [JsonDeserializer](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html). Google recommends:

> New applications should prefer TypeAdapter, whose streaming API is more efficient than this interface's tree API.

But I didn't notice any performance impact for my use. I might someday rewrite this to use a TypeAdapter, but this works for me in till then

```
class InfoboxDeserialiser implements JsonDeserializer<Infobox> {

    @Override
    public Infobox deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

        try {
            if (json.isJsonNull() || json.isJsonPrimitive()) {
                return null;
            }

            JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();

            Infobox infobox = new Infobox();

            JsonArray jsonContent = jsonObject.get("content").getAsJsonArray();
            JsonArray jsonMeta = jsonObject.get("meta").getAsJsonArray();

            infobox.content = new Content[jsonContent.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonContent.size(); i++) {
                infobox.content[i] = context.deserialize(jsonContent.get(i), Content.class);
            }

            infobox.meta = new Metum[jsonMeta.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonMeta.size(); i++) {
                infobox.meta[i] = context.deserialize(jsonContent.get(i), Metum.class);
            }

            return infobox;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Timber.e(e, "Failed to deserialise the infobox");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Where the classes are as follows

```
class Metum {
    public String dataType;
    public String value;
    public String label;
}

class Content {
    public String dataType;
    public String value;
    public String label;
    public Integer wikiOrder;
}
```

I register this deserializer while creating the service object

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Infobox.class, new InfoboxDeserialiser());
GsonConverterFactory converterFactory = GsonConverterFactory.create(gsonBuilder.create());
        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://api.duckduckgo.com/")
        .addConverterFactory(converterFactory);
```